# How to tell whether the current request is part of a cron run?

Tags: 7, cron

I have a module that needs to behave differently when its hooks are invoked during a cron run.  (For example, my module should redirect normal page requests, but avoid redirecting during a cron run, so that the cron run is not interrupted.)

How can I programmatically determine whether the current request is part of a cron run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `hook_cron_queue_info()` to set a global flag indicating that the current request is part of a cron run.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_cron_queue_info().
 *
 * hook_cron_queue_info rather than hook_cron, to ensure it executes before
 * any hook_cron implementations.
 */
function mymodule_cron_queue_info() {
  global $mymodule_in_cron;
  $mymodule_in_cron = TRUE;
}
```

Then, elsewhere in your module, you can check this flag:

```
global $mymodule_in_cron;
if (!empty($mymodule_in_cron)) {
  return;
}
```

This works both when invoking cron via the web server and via `drush cron`.